# Receive Twilio SMS .NET Core WEB API

Tags: .net-core, twilio, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to setup my `.netcore 1.0` server to receive SMS messages (Web API) that are sent to my `Twilio` number. I have searched SO and Google for an example and all point to MVC 5 which I cannot bring into my project. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I recommend you take a read through this blog post by my colleague Marcos, who wrote about checking the prices of Magic the Gathering cards using [SMS, Twilio and .NET Core](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/05/build-a-magic-the-gathering-sms-price-checker-with-twilio-and-net-core.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you